# ''Tire air leaking sound''

Tags: engine, motorcycle, yamaha

I have yamaha SZR bike. It is making weird sound lately. It is making ''tyre air leak sound'' but it is not certainly from the tire. It makes sound after 20-30 minutes interval. Im far from service area. Please suggest

Comment: Is the sound while riding/running or when it's just sitting there (off).

Answer (score 3):

The issue could be a vacuum forming in the fuel tank (check vents), looking at the yamaha site, it doesn't look like you have any active cooling (fan/radiator) so unlikely to be that.

There may also be an air-hose leaking somewhere or possibly a vacuum leak from the intake manifold.